# Integration with Lync 2010 and 2013 via SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sdk, lync, lync-client-sdk

I'm working on a small WPF application which changes the user's availability and status message in Lync.  I'm currently using the Lync 2010 SDK, but I'd like the app to support both 2010 and 2013 versions.

**What's the best way to support both versions in my application?**

Is the 2013 SDK backwards-compatible?  Will I need to include both DLL versions in my app and somehow select the correct one at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2013 sdk is not backwards compatible and it includes a fair amount not in the 2010 sdk.  For the availability work I'd use the 2010 SDK as that will work with the 2013 client.

Comment: @Paul thanks for answer but could you please be more specific on backward incompatibilities and "fair amount"?